# Rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Actually there is any easy way to prepend '/#!/' name prefix to all routes in rails 3?

like twitter and facebook
http://twitter.com/#!/username

I need that to manage ajax request.
Thanx very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's a built-in way to achieve it, though it wouldn't be impossible to write a JavaScript helper to turn to the server for new requests with `#!/` left out from the URLs, and catch all click events to turn them into URL hashes.